# pandoc: Undefined control sequence \colorbox

Tags: pdf, debian, latex, markdown, pandoc

## Problem

I have a file with a combination of **Markdown** and **LaTex** that I would like to convert into PDF. Pandoc seems to work in Ubuntu 20.04 but not in Debian 10.

## My Installation

```
# Installing Pandoc and dependencies
apt-get install pandoc texlive-xetex texlive-latex-recommended
```

## My Markdown

I have the following text in a file called **test.md**:

```
\centerline{\Large{\textbf{Test 1}}}

\colorbox{blue!25}{\Large{\textbf{Test 2}}}

**This is a test**
```

## Convertion

```
# Conversion
pandoc -V geometry:margin=0.7in -s test.md -o output.pdf
```

In Ubuntu 20.04 a beautiful PDF i generated.
In Debian 10 (Docker) I get the following error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.62 \colorbox
```

Am I missing some dependencies in Debian 10? Is there a way to see what Pandoc engine that is used by default? What am I doing wrong?

When running verbose mode it seems the installations are using different engines, however, when I specify the geometry driver such that they are the same, the problem remains.

```
# Debian 10
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: xetex

# Ubuntu 20.04
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex
```

## Update: Workaround

Reading several posts on similar problems, I first tried to add **\usepackage{xcolor}** to the start of the document, but that didn't work. Then I found out that you have to add a YAML-header and then it works. The original problem however still puzzles me.

```
# Adding this to the start of the document fixed the problem
---
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{xcolor}
output:
    pdf_document
---
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debian 10 (buster) [ships](https://packages.debian.org/buster/pandoc) with pandoc 2.2.1, while Ubuntu 20.04 (focal) [comes with](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/pandoc) pandoc 2.5. It seems that you hit a bug which was fixed in the later version.

However, this *is* curious. The changelog mentions that a bug like this was [fixed in version 2.6](https://pandoc.org/releases.html#pandoc-2.6-2019-01-30), which is newer than either of your versions. So I'm honestly a bit puzzled about the exact nature of the bug you triggered.